# Severity: Warning Message: Illegal string offset 'id' MY OWN PROJECT

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, offset

i have problem in code with my model/Master.php, in codeigniter. 

[***Here is screenshot of my view***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvXtZ.png)

model/Master.php:

```
function get_tasks($limit=20,$task_id=0,$page_num=1,$search='',$sortfield='default',$sort='sort')
{
    $data = array();
    $sortable_fields = array('id'=>'t.id','ime'=>'t.ime','sn_br'=>'t.sn_br','gar_stanje'=>'t.gar_stanje','opis_kvara'=>'t.opis_kvara','comment'=>'t.comment','task_assigned'=>'t.task_assigned','ime'=>'t.ime','prezime'=>'t.prezime','br_tel'=>'t.br_tel','email'=>'t.email','datum'=>'t.datum','account_id'=>'u3.account_id');
    $account_id = $this->session->userdata('account_id');
    $offset = ($page_num==1) ? 0 : ($page_num*$limit)-$limit;
    if ($task_id!=0){
        $this->db->select('t.id, t.ime, t.sn_br, t.gar_stanje,  t.opis_kvara, t.comment, u2.user_firstname as task_assigned, t.ime, t.prezime, t.br_tel, t.email, t.datum, u3.account_id');
        }else{
        $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.id, t.ime, t.sn_br, t.gar_stanje,  t.opis_kvara, t.comment, u2.user_firstname as task_assigned, t.ime, t.prezime, t.br_tel, t.email, t.datum, u3.account_id', FALSE);  
    }
    if ($task_id!=0){
        $this->db->where('t.id',(string)$task_id);
    }
    $this->db->where('u3.account_id',(string)$account_id);
    $this->db->where('t.task_status','1');
    $this->db->from('serv t');
    $this->db->join('users u2', 't.task_assigned = u2.user_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('accounts u3', 'u3.account_id = u3.account_id', 'inner');

    if ($task_id!=0){
        $this->db->limit(1);
    }else{
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    }
    if (array_key_exists($sortfield,$sortable_fields) && ($sort=='asc' || $sort=='desc')){
        $this->db->order_by($sortable_fields[$sortfield],strtoupper($sort));
    }else{
        $this->db->order_by('t.task_status ASC, t.datum DESC');
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    // echo $this->db->last_query();
    if ($query->num_rows()>0){
        $tasks = $query->result_array();
        if ($task_id!=0){
            $data['task'] = $tasks[0];
        }else{
            $data['serviss'] = $tasks;
        }
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `Count`');
        $data["total_rows"] = $query->row()->Count;
    }else{
        $data['serviss']['id'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['ime'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['prezime'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['br_tel'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['naziv_artikla'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['sn_br'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['gar_stanje'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['opis_kvara'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['opis_posla'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['utro_mater'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['comment'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['datum'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['datum_otp'] = 'Unable to find!';
        $data['serviss']['task_status'] = '0';
        $data["total_rows"] = '0';
    }
    return $data;   
}
```

views/default/servis.php

```
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
    <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')=='1'){ ?>
    <div id="msg_container2" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button id="msg_close_button2" type="button" class="close" onclick="$('#msg_container2').hide();">&times;</button>
      <span id="msg_content2"><?=$this->session->flashdata('msg_data')?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table_sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='id' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='id' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/id/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">ID</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='ime' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='ime' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/ime/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Ime</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='prezime' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='prezime' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/prezime/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Prezime</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='br_tel' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='br_tel' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/br_tel/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Broj telefona</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='naziv_artikla' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='naziv_artikla' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/naziv_artikla/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Naziv Artikla</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='sn_br' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='sn_br' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/sn_br/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Serijski broj</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='gar_stanje' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='gar_stanje' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/gar_stanje/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Pod garancijom</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='opis_kvara' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='opis_kvara' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/opis_kvara/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Opis Kvara</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='opis_posla' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='opis_posla' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/opis_posla/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Opis Posla</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='utro_mater' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='utro_mater' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/utro_mater/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Utroseni materijal</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='comment' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='comment' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/comment/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Komentar</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='datum' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='datum' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/datum/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Datum zaprimanja</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='datum_otp' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='datum_otp' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/datum_otp/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Datum otprimanja</a></th>
                <th class="s_header<?=($sortfield=='task_status' && $sort=='asc' ? ' s_asc' : ($sortfield=='task_status' && $sort=='desc' ? ' s_desc' : ''))?>"><a href="<?=url('servis/s/'.$search.'/task_status/'.($sort!='desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc').'/'.$limit.'/'.$page_num)?>">Posao zavrsen</a></th>

    </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
        if (!empty($task_data['serviss'])){
        foreach ($task_data['serviss'] as $t_key => $t_value) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="<?=url('servis/info/'.$t_value['id'])?>"><?=$t_value['naziv_artikla']?></a></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['ime']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['prezime']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['br_tel']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['naziv_artikla']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['sn_br']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['gar_stanje']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['opis_kvara']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['opis_posla']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['utro_mater']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['comment']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['datum']?></td>
                <td><?=$t_value['datum_otp']?></td>
                <td><?=$this->selects->task_status('','',$t_value['task_status'],1)?></td>                  
            </tr>
        <?php }}else{ ?>
            <tr>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
                <td>No Information</td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<?=$pagination_links?>
```

controllers/Servis.php

```
    public function s(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')==''){
        header('Location: '.url('home'));
    }else{
        $data = array();
        $data['search'] = urldecode(($this->uri->segment(4)!='' ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 'search'));
        $data['sortfield'] = ($this->uri->segment(5)!='' ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 'default');
        $data['sort'] = ($this->uri->segment(6)!='' ? $this->uri->segment(6) : 'sort');
        $data['limit'] = ($this->uri->segment(7)!='' ? $this->uri->segment(7) : 20);
        $data['page_num'] = ($this->uri->segment(8)!='' ? $this->uri->segment(8) : 1);
        $data['task_data'] = $this->master->get_tasks($data['limit'],'',$data['page_num'],$data['search'],$data['sortfield'],$data['sort']);
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['uri_segment'] = 8;
        $config['num_links'] = 2;
        $config['base_url'] = url('servis/s/'.$data['search'].'/'.$data['sortfield'].'/'.$data['sort'].'/'.$data['limit']);
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['task_data']['total_rows'];
        $config['per_page'] = $data['limit'];
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['meta']['title'] = 'Servis';
        $theme = $this->master->get_theme();
        $this->load->view($theme.'/servis',$data);
    }
}
```

Please, if someone know how to resolve this problem and reason witch is causes this problem, contact me or write Answer.

I am very grateful to all those who attempt to overcome the error.

---

### AFTER I CHANGED THE CODE

@Sugumar Venkatesan
After i changed:
foreach ($task_data['serviss'] as $t_key => $t_value) {} 
to 
foreach($task_data as $t_key => $t_value) {}

Now i geting message "unable to find", obviously now is problem with retrieve data from database.
[**My view after i changed the code**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvXtZ.png)

And also, @Alex Andrei here is echo from var_dump....

```
array(14) { ["id"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["ime"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["prezime"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["br_tel"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["naziv_artikla"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["sn_br"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["gar_stanje"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["opis_kvara"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["opis_posla"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["utro_mater"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["comment"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["datum"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["datum_otp"]=> string(15) "Unable to find!" ["task_status"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

Comment: Also you can't have duplicate keys in your array.

Comment: can you please do a `var_dump($task_data['serviss']))` in `views/default/servis.php` just inside the `if` clause. Here `if (!empty($task_data['serviss'])){` so we can see the structure of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
foreach ($task_data['serviss'] as $t_key => $t_value) {} 
should be 
foreach($task_data as $t_key => $t_value) {}
```

Comment: in the model, `$data['task_data'] = $this->master->get_tasks` then `return $data` then in the controller `$data` is passed to the view

Comment: @Sugumar Venkatesan But now i got a new problem. I edited my post so you can see what is now happend